# How to include sigar native libraries in sbt-native-packager Akka build?

Tags: scala, sbt, akka, sbt-native-packager, sigar

I'm just curious if there is some nice way to do that with Akka packaging.

I found some examples [here](https://github.com/muuki88/sbt-native-packager-examples/tree/master/rpm-sigar), but it was created for `rpm` build and I'm using these two plugins in my `build.sbt`:

```
.enablePlugins(AkkaAppPackaging)
  .enablePlugins(UniversalPlugin)
```

Actually I figured out one workaround by copying sigar libraries manually to directory where application starter script is generated.

There is also a need to set `-Djava.library.path=./sigar` to appropriate directory where sigar libraries are located, this can be set in `build.sbt` or changed later manually in generated scripts, by changing the `JAVA_OPTS`.

Comment: The rpm solution should be valid for your case as well. Can you describe your problem? Do the libs don't show up, if you add them like in the rpm example?

Comment: Yes, they didn't show up.

Comment: But I'll check again. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did

```
  lazy val sigarJavaOpts = "-Djava.library.path=./sigar"

  libraryDependencies ++= Dependencies.sigar

  mappings in Universal ++= MappingsHelper directory getClass.getClassLoader.getResource("sigar").getFile

  bashScriptExtraDefines += s"""addJava "$sigarJavaOpts" """

  javaOptions in run += sigarJavaOpts
```

Note that I placed sigar files in my resources folder. You might also need to import from the following

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager.Universal
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.MappingsHelper
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.Keys.bashScriptExtraDefines
```

Also I do have a Dependencies object in which I have

```
  val sigar = Seq(
    "org.fusesource" % "sigar" % "1.6.4"
  )
```